# stdWrap and optionSplit for HMENU object

Tags: typoscript, typo3-8.x

```
lib.language = COA
lib.language {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        special = language
        special.value = 0,1
        special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
        wrap =
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            noBlur = 1
            NO = 1
            NO {
                doNotLinkIt = 1
                linkWrap = <li>|</li>
                stdWrap.override = [int] English || [de-de] Deutsch
                stdWrap {
                    typolink {
                        parameter.data = page:uid
                        additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1
                        addQueryString = 1
                        addQueryString.exclude = L,id,no_cache
                        addQueryString.method = GET
                        no_cache = 0
                    }
                }
            }
            ACT < .NO
            ACT.linkWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
    }
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
}

.......

lib.language.10.1.NO.stdWrap.override = [us] English || [de] Deutsch
```

Having the previous piece of default TypoScript code to build a language menu, where I overwrite the display of language labels with the last line of Typoscript here shown, the frontend shows:

```
[int] English [de] Deutsch
```

(a mix of both lines).

Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add typoscript line:

```
lib.language.10.1.ACT.stdWrap.override = [us] English || [de] Deutsch
```

With your line, you overwrite the NO settings after copied them to the ACT settings